# Как упростить код Ребус: BMW+ZAZ=MOTO

Tags: c++, c, циклы, комбинаторика

}

```
        for (int M = 1; M <= 9; ++M) {
            if (M == A || M == B) {
                continue;
            }
    
     
            for (int O = 0; O <= 9; ++O) {
                if (O == A || O == B || O == M) {
                    continue;   
            }
         
                for (int T = 0; T <= 9; ++T) {
                    if (T == A || T == B || T == M || T == O) {
                        continue;
                    }
                           
                    for (int W = 0; W <= 9; ++W) {
                     if (W == A || W == B || W == M || W == O || W == T) {
                         continue;
                     }          
                     for (int Z = 0; Z <= 9; ++Z) {
                         if (Z == A || Z == B || Z == M || Z == O || Z == T) {
                             continue;
                         } 
                          
                         
                         int BMV = B * 100 * M * 10 + W;
                         int ZAZ = Z * 100 * A * 10 + Z;
                         int MOTO = M * 1000 + O * 100 + T * 10 + O;            
                
                         if (BMV + ZAZ == MOTO) {
                             cout << B << M << W << " + " << Z << A << Z << " - " << M << O << T << O << endl;
                         }
                     }
                   }
               }
```

Comment: Так `=MOTOR` или `BMV + ZAZ == MOTO`? Первый решения не имеет, второй имеет 3 решения. Далее, я бы использовал перестановки. Это не считая, того, что давал бы код не отрывком из обрывка...

Comment: Любезный User70, не меняйте так катастрофически свой вопрос после того, как его задали. Не делайте из читателей недоумевающих, гм... ну, вы поняли. Тем более не следует убирать код и менять метку языка. Тут уж вы просто выставляете меня дураком — у вас вышло, что вопрос задал я, да еще и на Pascal. И ответил не пойми на что на С++...

Comment: Не нужно полностью менять текст вопроса после того, как на него дали ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template<class RandIt, class Compare>
bool next_k_permutation(RandIt first, RandIt mid, RandIt last, Compare comp)
{
    std::sort(mid, last, std::not_fn(comp));
    return std::next_permutation(first, last, comp);
}

template<class RandIt>
bool next_k_permutation(RandIt first, RandIt mid, RandIt last)
{
    return next_k_permutation(first, mid, last,std::less<>());
}

int main()
{
    //         B M W Z A O T
    int v[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    do {
        if (((v[0]+v[3]-v[5])*10+v[1]+v[4]-v[6])*10+v[2]+v[3]-v[5] == 1000*v[1])
            std::cout
                << v[0] << v[1] << v[2] << "+"
                << v[3] << v[4] << v[3] << "="
                << v[1] << v[5] << v[6] << v[5] << "\n";
    } while(next_k_permutation(v,v+7,v+10));
}
```

[годится](https://ideone.com/xIV5jL)?

Comment: Как насчёт улучшения кода: `int &B = v[0];`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Можно, конечно... Но эти `v[]` используются буквально по 2 раза, так что не уверен, что это что-то даст. Кстати, мне больше нравится `enum { B,M,W,...` — тогда будут `v[B]`, как бы с намеком — код для `B` :)

Comment: `(10 * (10 * B + M) + W) + (10 * (10 * Z + A) + Z) == (10 * (10 * (10 * M + O) + T) + O)` - я имел ввиду схему Горнера и естественную нотацию в терминах B, M, W... .

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Если вы присмотритесь, то увидите схему Горнера и у меня (8 сложений/вычитаний и 3 умножения у меня против 8 сложений и 7 умножений у вас), только она в случае *не с переменными* особого смысла не имеет. А о *естественной нотации* я и ответил, что мне кажется, через `enum` лучше...